# Chrome Extension: Modifying a built in function for all webworkers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So here's a bit of background. I need to intercept the return data from a fetch request. I already know how to do that. By injecting this code in the webpage I can read the response body of a fetch. Like this:

```
var proxyFetch = fetch;
window.fetch = async function () {
    var response = proxyFetch(...arguments);
    // a lot of other code as well
    return response;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't modify the fetch function for any web workers. I don't have access to their 'this' context. My best bet is something to do with WorkerGlobalScope but I don't know if that object can do what I want.

My second idea was to do something like before the page loads.

```
window.Worker = class extends window.Worker{
    constructor(){
        // Take the url they passed into webworker.
        // Fetch the url to get the raw javascript.
        // Append my javascript to it.
        // Turn it into a blob url
        // Now I have my javascript running in every web worker
        // 
        // The problem here is that we are not allowed to use asynchronous calls in the constructor.
        // I am stumped on this option as well.
    }
}
```

I've looked into WebRequest but they don't allow us to look at the response body of network requests.

I played around with this a lot to see if I could modify the globalThis or WorkerGlobalScope for every webworker on the page so I can modify the fetch but I could not find a way.

```
  var code = "postMessage('hello world');"
  var blob = new Blob([code], { type: 'application/javascript' });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var worker = new Worker(url);
  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
  };
```

Comment: 1) Inherit the Worker override from `Proxy` so you can construct the real worker asynchronously, and transparently invoke the original methods when ready. 2) Use XMLHttpRequest in synchronous mode inside your constructor proxy (it'll print a warning in devtools console but you can ignore it)

Comment: I forgot that synchronous mode was a thing. I might go with the proxy option since it's safer.

Comment: @wOxxOm I could not figure out the proxy solution so I guess I have to use synchronous mode.